# How to disable the map from esc to meta?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, evil, terminal-emacs

I installed the `oh-my-emacs` configuration and try to use emacs in the terminal.

`oh-my-emacs` configuration enables `evil-mode` in default, and my problem is that, I found `esc` is mapped to `meta`, while the original `command` in my Mac is somehow disabled.. These kinds of remapping do not happen when I use emacs with `oh-my-emacs` configuration in GUI. So I basically have no idea why.

I really cannot get used to the map from `esc` to `meta`, even though `esc` can still be used to switch from input mode to command mode in `evil`. I just want to disable this mapping. Does anyone know how to do it?

By the way, I found I can use `space+j` to achieve the `M-x`, so I am not worried that I can not use `command` in Mac to invoke `M-x` command. But basically why the `command` does not work in terminal environment?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the modes at issue, but perhaps the variable `meta-prefix-char` could be relevant if the user wants to separate the `esc` key from the `meta` key.  I have chosen to do this for my own personal reasons, and before any of my libraries are loaded and before the variables defining the various key mode-maps are established, I set the `meta-prefix-char` to `nil` instead of the default `27` on OSX.  NOTE:  This is not the Emacs default behavior, but is rather a customized preference that very few people seem to prefer -- i.e., I'm apparently a rare bird.